# Latex command escape

Tags: xetex, security

We are using latex for pdf generation on our server.
I would like to  increase the security of our system with  latex command escaping for data content ie remove all latex / tex / xelatex executable code. My question is if it is enough to remove  the '\' character? Or are there any other special characters   I should remove as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove them, just use `\detokenize{...}` around all unknown data then  `\` (and `^` which you also need to make safe) will just be normal characters that that typeset as themselves) (you probably want to make `%` catcode 12 as well.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely use this but unfortunately this is not enough.You can simply  use }{ and the escaping does not work anymore i.e:\detokenize{bla }{\input{/etc/passwd} blo}  also they may be a use case where I need to enable some latex commands for example \thepage. Do you know any other dangerous characters except \ and ^ ?

Comment: @sherif I was assuming the incoming data was plain text without any tex commands so wouldn't have any tex commands needing `{}`

Comment: Well me too but  that changed yesterday :D Is it possible to close detokenize any other way than } ?

Comment: Ok so I have read a little about catcodes   If I blacklist  the \catcode command (and \def of course ) in the entire document then I can assume that  there is no way to escape detokenize except using }. If there is no package declaring another cat 2 character

Comment: @sherif I really can't guess your use case here. What you describe sounds wrong. If you are accepting user input including tex commands then pretty much anything can be redefined. If you are normalizing user input so it is not interpreted as tex then you do not need to do anything about specific commands such as `\def` or `\catcode` as they will never be seen.

Comment: I see the security on more then one layer. If one layer is broken the other should hold  ie I have to expect that someone breaks detokenize. Anyway thanks for the help I accept your answer but please tell me if there is any other dangerous characters besides ^ and \   (and }{ ) in default config

Comment: @sherif probably not, if you make `^` and `\ ` safe then you can't access any tex commands other than active characters for things like utf8 decoding, although it depends what you mean by dangerous null (ascii 0) is by default has teh catcode of an invalid character so if you get it on input you will get a tex error (it can't redefine anything but it might stop your job)